# os.listdir return strange string of filename with special characters

Tags: python, special-characters, google-colaboratory, listdir

Suppose I have the following files in `path`, which is in my Google drive that is connected to a Python 3 Colab notebook:

(Here, the # line represents the output)

```
ls = os.listdir(path)
print (ls)
# ['á.csv', 'b.csv']
```

Every seems ok, but if I write

```
'á.csv' in ls
# False
```

But should returns True. However, if I repeat the last code, but instead of writing 'á.csv' I copy-paste it manually from `print (ls)`, it returns True.

Thanks

ps: The problem is not exactly with that filename, is with several filenames which contains special characters (namely í, á, é, ó, ñ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize the file list before comparing them.

```py
from unicodedata import normalize
ls = [normalize('NFC', f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
# compare
normalize('NFC', 'á.csv') in ls
# or just 'á.csv' in ls
```

Comment: This works.  the last normalize is unnecessary although prefered for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because some diacritic characters in Unicode have duplicates. That is, while some characters appear identical, they may be different characters with different codes. Try `'á'.encode()` once by writing `á` and once again by copy-pasting as you did. If the bytes look different, that's because they are different characters that look identical.

Comment: you're right! written ```'í'.encode()``` returns ```\xc3\xad``` and copied returns ```i\xcc\x81``` Now How could I fix it? Both are in utf-8, however one codes the í and the other for the accent mark. Also in my offline Python it replicate the problem (I don't know why before it doesn't but I will edit my post) so maybe it is something of ```listdir```

Comment: You can get rid of all accents from the file names, so long as there are no collisions. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string) to find out how.